# How to log in as different user to Google API v3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-calendar-api

So I'm trying to create a new calendar, but i want to be able to specify what google account to create it in, assuming i have the credentials for said account, which i do. The code bellow creates it on the currently signed in user, or requires user interaction to allow access. Is there a way to specify an user and run the command on the background. I essentially just want to add a calendar to my account when the program runs, but i cant guarantee that my account will be logged in at the time.

I believe this was possible with the version 2 of the google api through ClientLogin, but i'm trying to use version 3.

```
import gflags
import httplib2

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.file import Storage
from oauth2client.client import OAuth2WebServerFlow
from oauth2client.tools import run

FLAGS = gflags.FLAGS
FLOW = OAuth2WebServerFlow(
    client_id='MY_CLIENT_KEY',
    client_secret='MY_CLIENT_SECRET',
    scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar',
    user_agent='MyApp/v1')
storage = Storage('calendar.dat')
credentials = storage.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid == True:
  credentials = run(FLOW, storage)

http = httplib2.Http()
http = credentials.authorize(http)
service = build(serviceName='calendar', version='v3', http=http)

calendar = {
    'summary': 'Test3',
    'timeZone': 'America/New_York'
}

created_calendar = service.calendars().insert(body=calendar).execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With V3, you'll need to use a Service Account in order to act as the user. The process is described in the [Google Drive documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation), you just need to use Calendar API v3 scopes and references instead of Google Drive API.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to store the OAuth2 refresh token and use it to grab valid access tokens even if the user is not logged in. See my reply to [google Calendar api v3 Auth only for first time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23759906/google-calendar-api-v3-auth-only-for-first-time/23817942#23817942)